# Bootstrap block positioning

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with block positioning as on a picture.
[image](http://www.online-upload.com/partials/test_uploads/Bez%C2%A0tytu%C5%82u_15.02.17_18.24.07.png)
This happens when I write class col-sm-6 bootstrap. I tried to add class clearfix, but was not the result.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card-row clearfix">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 clearfix">
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-5.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-8.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-8.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 clearfix">
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-6.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-7.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-7.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mod-col-3">
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-7.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-5.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-8.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mod-col-4">
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-8.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                        <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-6.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-7.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to become a 3 block to an empty position and 4 position on the block 3 blocks?

Comment: do you know what `.clearfix` does?

Comment: Yes, it's cleaning of floating elements, but I don't know of any other options

Comment: Its used for a parent element to clear its floated children, so that the parent inherits the height of the tallest child.

Comment: where's your CSS? We need a [mcve] of the problem

Comment: the Bootstrap columns represent the box for the image. So col-sm-6 can be fine. You need to make the image within to be displayed: block . If it is what you want. I dont understand exactly what you are trying to reach. But the grid classes you added by default change size according to the grid parameters. Nest the image within these blocks and it should be fine

Comment: When I use the class Col-SM-6, I would like that to the blocks were in two rows, I have such blocks 4 and they have different sizes, the first two are normal, but the third will melt into place 4 blocks and 4 block becomes below

Comment: `col-*` should be the immediate children of `.row` not `card-row`. There are other issues. Like what is `mod-col-3`? You need to clean it up and create a mininal example.

Comment: I deleted div card-row, mod-col-3 it was class empty, I think problem stems from the fact that I have a 4 block whose height is different and I wish that when col-sm-6 units were 1-2, 3-4 but unit 2 has a height less than a block 1 and block 3 becomes lower unit 2 I do not know how to solve it

Comment: It is because of the height. That's why you need clearfix, masonry or equal height columns.